# How to add smileys to django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am new to django and know almost nothing of js. I am wondering what is the best way to integrate smileys to my app, preferably using jQuery.

I have seen some Django smileys packages like [this](https://bitbucket.org/codekoala/django-smileys) but they seem abandoned or quite outdated and did not work for me.

So appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is application for Django [django-emoticons](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-emoticons). Last commit was 19 July 2014, so it seems like up to date. Check it out!

Comment: It is a very handy module and works flawlessly. Thanks for the hint.